# Rolling regression - but get only a single beta

Tags: r, regression, beta, rolling-computation

I am trying to run the below code in r as I would like to calculate a rolling regression over a 10 day time period and I would like to calculate this every day. However, I get a columns consisting of a single coefficient and beta for the entire time period of 5 years.  what am I doing wrong here. Please help.

```
rollapply(mydatareturns, width=10, by=1, function(x) coef(lm(mydatareturns$v1 ~ mydatareturns$v2, data=as.data.frame(x))), by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

*mydatareturns* is the daily return of the independent variable v2 and the dependent variable v1.

Comment: dont pass in the whole column as follows: `rollapply(mydatareturns, width=10, by=1, function(x) coef(lm(v1 ~ v2, data=as.data.frame(x))), by.column=FALSE, align="right")`